# Error al extraer texto de base de datos

Tags: symfony2, twig

Con php nativo extraigo de una base de datos un texto que contiene lo típico texto, imágenes, videos etc..

Estoy migrando la web y estoy utilizando para ello **Symfony 2**

El contenido por ejemplo de un campo de la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
<p style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:14px>hola quetal..etc</span> 
    <img src="servidor"..etc/>
```

Hago lo normal llamo al controlador y me realiza una **QUERY** utilizando el método de symfony 2 `createQueryBuilder`

Y en la vista recorro el array que me devuelve la QUERY:

```
{% for x in articles1 %}

    <div class="post-article">{{x.texto}}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

El problema, es que me devuelve el texto eliminando todas las etiquetas  por lo que me muestra todo como un

`<p>contenido del texto sin importar si tiene mas etiqueta dentro</p>`

de texto sin mostrar negritas, imágenes y demás enlaces.

¿Conocéis alguna forma que Symfony 2 tenga para mostrarme las cosas tal y como son?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Además:

Se puede mejorar un poquillo, así (sobre todo para debug, claro):

```
{{ x.texto | raw | default("post sin texto") }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

También puedes configurar el autoescape en Twig:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options

Answer (score 1):

Twig tiene el 'modo seguro'; es decir, la variable no puede parsear datos html directo.

para poder mostrar los datos completos, debes usar la etiqueta

```
{% autoescape %}
{{ var|raw }} {# esta variable no será escapada #}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, tenía puesto ese código pero al mirar el controlador.. Tenían aplicada la función strtags y por eso nome mostraba nada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para que twig no escape el contenido de tus variables es necesario el uso del filtro `raw` de esta manera:

```
{% for x in articles1 %}
    <div class="post-article">{{x.texto|raw}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, el problema era como comentaba arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Ojo que ese tag solo funciona en Twig >= 1.8

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Lo más rápido es utilizar el filtro:

```
{{ x.texto | raw }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html